# How do I create a custom managed list?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I saw from the docs that sitecore commerce has a managed list feature that can be used to mantain and return a list of entity (CommerceEntity).

I have been used it to get the list of pending orders and stuff like that.
However those list were out-of-the-box in the commerce engine.

Now I would like to create a new managed list which returns a list of orders that have a custom status, and keep it up-to-date when an order change its status e.g. from "Pending" to the custom one.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed lists are just strings, they're not registered anywhere. You can add an order to a custom one by adding it to the Orders `ListMembershipComponent` or `TransientListMembershipComponent` (tl;dr the latter in your case) and then persisting the entity using `IPersistEntityPipeline`.

Implementation-wise, the SQL plugin has pipeline blocks in `IPersistEntityPipeline` which create back-references for any managed lists.

Regular list memberships remain two-way (list to entity, and entity to list via the component) and typically represent things that can never change (all orders are in the `Orders` list as well as the `Customer-{id}-Orders` list).

Transient list memberships are meant for things that can change, like status lists. As such, the SQL plugin block removes the component from the entity after they create the back-references resulting in a one way (list to entity)

You can find some great examples of changing status + assigning transient list memberships by peeking at the blocks in `ICreateOrderPipeline` / `IPendingOrdersMinionPipeline` / `IReleasedOrdersMinionPipeline`

Answer (score 0):

To create or have a new list for your order Entity.

```
order.GetComponent<TransientListMembershipsComponent>().Memberships.Add("CustomStatusOrders");
```

To make the list searchable using list API, add the list name in PlugIn.SQL.Sharding.PolicySet-1.0.0.json.

[image]